# tablet / laptop same resolution: bootstrap responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website with Bootstrap 3, and I'm having an issue due to resolutions screen.

My laptop and tablet both uses 1280x800 resolution. The thing is my website has a background video (HTML5) that has autoplay attribute. In desktop it's working OK, but not in tablet, I mean, website is loaded and everything goes OK but instead of playing the video, it shows a black screen.
Both devices uses same resolution so I'm not able to fix tablet's view because it shares the same resolution that Desktop's.

This is the code I wrote:

```
 <header class="video-bg hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
  <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
    <video autoplay autobuffer loop muted class="hidden-xs hidden-sm overlay-video embed-responsive-item" id="vidMain"><!-- visible-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg overlay-video embed-responsive-item-->
      <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" class='embed-responsive-item'/>
    </video>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Any chance to fix it?

Comment: that chance to fix may increase if you provide sample code. this question is very broad as is. could it be the tablet and not the resolution?(take your pc browser off full screen and resize it with your mouse)
does video still work? (might be the tablet)
video goes black? (provide code.)
o) ok its the tablet. but what about the tablet? (check if there are issues related to the type of tablet as well as the browsers you use on the tablet.)

Comment: this is not an answer, but may help you find one
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1044374
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/T6hNpETUu_U

both links mention the issue lying in the hardware acceleration